# Find transition probability matrix

Tags: self-study, markov-process, transition-matrix

A box contains 3 balls. Each is either white or red. The game is to draw a ball from each period. If red is drawn, a white is replaced. But if white is drawn, all the balls in the box is replaced by red. Define $X_n = i$, $i$ is the number of white balls at period $n$. Determine transition probability matrix.

I got confused in the part when a white ball is drawn, all the balls are replaced by red.

Comment: The balls all being replaced by red just means that in the next state there are 0 white balls, so $X_{n + 1} = 0$.  Is that helpful?

Comment: Yes thanks. What if initially all 3 balls are red, so the first period would have 1 white ball and 2 reds, right? And what if initially all 3 are white, so the first period would have 0 white balls since they are all replaced by red now. How do I present that in a transition matrix?

Comment: It may be helpful to decide how many states are there. That will give you the dimensions of your matrix.